# How to format PostgeSQL query results in PHP to return GeoJSON object?

Tags: postgis, leaflet, php

I'm building a small map application with Leaflet and PostGIS. I'm having an issue similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38408633/postgresql-geojson-php-javascript/38433601) where using pg_fetch_all is returning the data I want, but buried in an associative array.

When I run the query in PgAdmin I get the results I expect as a feature collection that works on [geosjson.io](https://geojson.io).  What I'm having issues is formating the response, in that the query's result raw is just `Resource id #3`. Using `pg_fetch_all` returns the GeoJSON object nested into an associative array looking like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [row_to_json] => {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[8.697130556,50.123908333,108.5]},"properties":{"id":3,"photo":"/Users/Nizz0k/Desktop/Peng/IMG_3475.jpeg","type":"Quote"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[8.691429401,50.115307684,105.7]},"properties":{"id":4,"photo":"/Users/Nizz0k/Desktop/Peng/IMG_3025.jpeg","type":"Quote"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[8.694072891,50.119541651,111.5]},"properties":{"id":5,"photo":"/Users/Nizz0k/Desktop/Peng/IMG_1274.jpeg","type":"Drawing and Tag"}}
```

So, how can I either format the response better, or pull the nested object out of the associative array?

My aim is to get GeoJSON for a Leaflet map. I'm querying a shapefile of single locations that I want some attributes associated.

Here's my query and code snippet:

```
$query = "SELECT row_to_json(fc)
FROM ( SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features
FROM (SELECT 'Feature' As type
   , ST_AsGeoJSON(lg.geom)::json As geometry
   , row_to_json((SELECT l FROM (SELECT id, photo, type) As l
     )) As properties
  FROM public.\"Peng\" As lg   ) As f )  As fc;";

$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
$geodata = pg_fetch_all($result);
print_r($geodata);
```

How can I both query and output a GeoJSON object? It's unclear to me why the output is getting wrapped in the array this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the answer is just correctly accessing the data in the array with `$geodata[0]['row_to_json']`.